# Как захватыать поток процесса вместе с ANSI кодировкой в Qt C++

Tags: c++, qt

Пытаюсь сделаю терминал в форме, от [сюда](https://www.cyberforum.ru/qt/thread2552750.html) взят инструмент, удалось реализовать и запускать процессы, которые отображают своё выполнение в текстовом поле на форме. небольшая часть кода:

```
    void Process::readResult(){
    emit lineRead(process->readAllStandardOutput());
    emit lineRead(process->readAllStandardError());

}

void Process::writeQString(QString str) {
    if (process->state() == QProcess::ProcessState::Running)
        process->write(str.toUtf8());
}
```

ну и отображение:

```
void MainWindow::getProcessLine(QByteArray output)
{

    QTextCodec *codec = QTextCodec::codecForName("cp-866");
    QString pStr = codec->toUnicode(output.data());
    ui->plainTextEdit->appendPlainText(pStr.trimmed());
}
```

Соответственно если я использую команды, в которых результат использует кодировку ANSI, то я в текстовом поле получаю все эти символы кодировки в перемешку с основным текстом.

*[33m Device #1: Not a native Intel runtime..[0m
[33m  You can use but do not report related errors.[0m
Started: Tue
[2K
Stopped: Tue
[31mNo devices found/left.[0m*

такие символы как: [0m [33m и так далее. 
Подскажите, пожалуйста, как исключить данные символы из вывода? Или есть возможность отображать вывод с данной кодировкой в текстовом поле?
Спасибо.

Comment: cp-866 это кодировка MS DOS

Comment: вы куда подключаетесь то?  `[0m [33m` это не кодировка, это управляющие последовательности для терминала, типа цвет сменить

Comment: @user7860670 а что необходимо вводить?

Comment: @PavelGridin в примере всё указано, все коннекты и прочее. Я понимаю что это последовательность, которая определяют формат текста в терминале. Но возможно ли данную последовательность (эти коды) так же захватывать и отображать текст в нужном формате их в текстовом поле на форме программы? Спасибо.

Comment: Удалось решить проблему, сначала сделать [это](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26500429/qtextedit-and-colored-bash-like-output-emulation/26524823#26524823), потом [это](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61798302/13023647)